# Forest inventory and lidar

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a dataset combining both lidar point cloud and individual tree inventory (positions, crown diameter,...) on a forested area.

Comment: Where is the location you are looking for ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few websites that you can go to

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar   Look at the External Links at the bottom

https://www.usgs.gov/science/science-explorer?lq=LIDAR

http://donnees4free.blogspot.com/2016/10/new-free-lidar-data-sources-list.html

https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

http://gisgeography.com/top-6-free-lidar-data-sources/

Comment: Thank you for your help !
It appears I don't have any trouble finding lidar data, but I can't find any tree inventory that fits my requirements... Do you think I can find something in EarthExplorer (i dont feel so...)?

Comment: You would have to research it on how to use it with the LIDAR.   I'd go google and it type it "Forest Inventory LIDAR" and it brings up a several list that you would have to read it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=Forest+Inventory+LIDAR

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a site that combines both tree inventory open data and LiDAR open data. You might have to compare the coverage of a number of unrelated sites and hope they coincide.

For LiDAR open data a good portal is [OpenTopography](http://opentopo.sdsc.edu/datasets), you can download small areas. I would encourage you to create an account as this will increase your download limit.

The [US Interagency Elevation Inventory](https://coast.noaa.gov/inventory/%20%22US%20Interagency%20Elevation%20Inventory) is a great portal as well. It will direct you to external data repositories but the coverage is awe inspiring.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in fact, I am fully aware of many free lidar data sources (I already have an opentopography account), but I struggle with the tree inventory part...

Comment: No problem, sorry I only know half the answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This question is several years old and things have progressed a little.

Its still rare find contemporaneous lidar and forest inventory data. Its also rare to find open-access forest inventory data. I have been told by people at the UK Forestry Commission that GDPR prevents inventory data from being released to the public! They are also afraid of people tampering with the inventory plots that they revisit.

Fortunately, the USFS is more enlightened. The [Forest Inventory and Analysis (FIA) Database](https://apps.fs.usda.gov/fia/datamart/datamart.html) is an excellent source of freely available forest inventory data. You can download data for each US state at a variety of spatial scales: plot, sub-plot, individual tree. The individual tree data contains measurements such as:

- tree species
- DBH and height
- estimated timber volume, biomass, carbon content
- a subjective assessment of crown condition (crown position and vigor).

The volume of data is enormous. Fortunately, there is an r package ([rFIA](https://rfia.netlify.app/)) which makes things easier. The tutorials show how to download the data and use it to estimate forest attributes etc.

**Reference**:
Stanke, H., Finley, A. O., Weed, A. S., Walters, B. F., & Domke, G. M. (2020). rFIA: An R package for estimation of forest attributes with the US Forest Inventory and Analysis database. Environmental Modelling & Software, 127, 104664.